Is it possible to make a D3D12 application in C?
I've seen a lot of posts asking if you can make something using D3D11 and C, but not any that ask if you can make an app using D3D12 and C.
I've searched the web for something but haven't really been able to find anything big.

It's written in C++, so I don't think it's worth writing it in C, even if it might be possible to link and create C-wrappers around every function.

A) Why? B) Why?

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to clarify, please. -- What is the difference between "make something" and "make an app"? -- In principle, you can, but it might be hard (for you). So what are you asking actually?

Sorry for taking a while to respond, I'm just asking because I just wanted to know if it was POSSIBLE. Not feasible.

While only C++ is officially supported, most headers are written in C so it should be possible to make an app. Due to lack of documentation, it will be harder than using C++, but not impossible.
You need C++ for the helper structures and functions in d3dx12.h. These are a major part of the library that makes it easier to develop applications. However, they are just helper classes using the core features of the library. Nothing stops you from using the core features directly.
Here is a demo project using C: https://github.com/zenny-chen/Use-Direct3D-12-Compute-Shader-in-C-Basic-

Yes it's absolutely possible !
Microsoft ensure to always write C portable code even in C++ but I prefer to advise you for your own sanity and comfort to prefer C++ over C if you're not very comfortable with it.
You'll have a really hard / long time programming it in C.

msvc does not even support C fully.

You don't need MSVC to compile C/C++ code

clicking through the official samples for d3d12, I do not see any way to just adapt them to C, so if such a way exists, please explain. Samples like these: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/creating-a-basic-direct3d-12-component#class-d3d12hellotriangle

https://github.com/rdunnington/d3d12-hello-triangle
Here's an example of how to achieve it ;)
But as I said earlier :
C++ is a better option, doing this in C is a waste of time

"Microsoft" and "portable" in the same sentence.

C++ code that can be ported to C

Note that modern MSVC does support C11 and C17. See Microsoft Learn for details.

No. The only official language supported is C++.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/directx-12-programming-environment-set-up#supported-languages

You can technically get C COM bindings working for DirectX12 since the headers are generated by MIDL, but the D3DX12 utility header is C++ only. There are also no samples for C bindings, and likely no test coverage at all.

@ChuckWalbourn well if we go that way we could write a C library and use D3D12 from Python, or java, or lua
